# Is it possible to sort Inventory items on a console version of the game, and if so, how?

Tags: the-witcher-3

For the console version of *Witcher 3*, is it possible to sort Inventory items like it is on the PC version? And if so, how do I do it?

As far as I know, at least, you can sort the Inventory as I recall seeing a "Sort" button at the bottom-left corner.

Comment: As of patch 1.07 (now out on at least PS4) you have sorting options for things like price etc.

Answer (score 1):

The inventory will automatically sort once you've "looked at" each new item (new items are indicated by an asterisk) by highlighting it with the cursor. After you have done this, the inventory will be auto-sorted the next time you open it.

This also applies to using the gamepad on PC; there is no way to manually sort your inventory unless you are using mouse/keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

On PS4, press L3 (clicking the left joy stick) then you'll get sorting options. It's a bit odd because it only sorts once you close. I usually hit L3 then close which defaults "sorting by type". You must of course be in the inventory view for this option.

I'm sure there is an equivalent for Xbox. Not sure what console you are using.

Comment: This is incorrect. You must press R3, not L3

Answer (score 0):

On the PS4 version of *Witcher 3: Wild Hunt*, you must open the inventory and press R3, which is pressing down on the right joystick. I'm not sure how to do it on the XBox version.